# Sum previously derived elements in xslt at the end

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have a XML as below -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Page_14_Direct_Premiums_Written">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Region>AL</wd:Region>
        <wd:Fire_DPW>0</wd:Fire_DPW>
        <wd:Allied_DPW>0</wd:Allied_DPW>
        <wd:Private_Flood_DPW>0</wd:Private_Flood_DPW>
        <wd:Farmowners_Multiple_Peril_DPW>0</wd:Farmowners_Multiple_Peril_DPW>
        <wd:Homeowners_Multiple_Peril_DPW>0</wd:Homeowners_Multiple_Peril_DPW>
        <wd:Commercial_Multiple_Peril_Non-Liability_DPW>0</wd:Commercial_Multiple_Peril_Non-Liability_DPW>
        <wd:CF_SCommercial_Multiple_Peril_Liability_DPW>0</wd:CF_SCommercial_Multiple_Peril_Liability_DPW>
        <wd:Ocean_Marine_DPW>0</wd:Ocean_Marine_DPW>
        <wd:Inland_Marine_DPW>0</wd:Inland_Marine_DPW>
        <wd:Earthquake_DPW>0</wd:Earthquake_DPW>
        <wd:Workers_Compensation_DPW>0</wd:Workers_Compensation_DPW>
        <wd:Other_Liability_Occurrence_DPW>-431</wd:Other_Liability_Occurrence_DPW>
        <wd:Other_Liability_Claims_Made_DPW>0</wd:Other_Liability_Claims_Made_DPW>
        <wd:Excess_Workers_Compensation_DPW>0</wd:Excess_Workers_Compensation_DPW>
        <wd:Products_Liability_Occurrence_State_Page_DPW>0</wd:Products_Liability_Occurrence_State_Page_DPW>
        <wd:Products_Liability_Claims_Made_State_Page_DPW>0</wd:Products_Liability_Claims_Made_State_Page_DPW>
        <wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_No_Fault_DPW>0</wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_No_Fault_DPW>
        <wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_Liability_Other_DPW>0</wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_Liability_Other_DPW>
        <wd:Commercial_Auto_No_Fault_DPW>0</wd:Commercial_Auto_No_Fault_DPW>
        <wd:Commercial_Auto_Liability_Other_DPW>0</wd:Commercial_Auto_Liability_Other_DPW>
        <wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_Physical_Damage_DPW>0</wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_Physical_Damage_DPW>
        <wd:Commercial_Auto_Physical_Damage_DPW>0</wd:Commercial_Auto_Physical_Damage_DPW>
        <wd:Aircraft_DPW>0</wd:Aircraft_DPW>
        <wd:Fidelity_DPW>0</wd:Fidelity_DPW>
        <wd:Surety_DPW>0</wd:Surety_DPW>
        <wd:Burglary_Theft_DPW>0</wd:Burglary_Theft_DPW>
        <wd:Boiler_Machinery_DPW>0</wd:Boiler_Machinery_DPW>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Region>AL</wd:Region>
        <wd:Fire_DPW>0</wd:Fire_DPW>
        <wd:Allied_DPW>0</wd:Allied_DPW>
        <wd:Private_Flood_DPW>0</wd:Private_Flood_DPW>
        <wd:Farmowners_Multiple_Peril_DPW>0</wd:Farmowners_Multiple_Peril_DPW>
        <wd:Homeowners_Multiple_Peril_DPW>0</wd:Homeowners_Multiple_Peril_DPW>
        <wd:Commercial_Multiple_Peril_Non-Liability_DPW>0</wd:Commercial_Multiple_Peril_Non-Liability_DPW>
        <wd:CF_SCommercial_Multiple_Peril_Liability_DPW>0</wd:CF_SCommercial_Multiple_Peril_Liability_DPW>
        <wd:Ocean_Marine_DPW>0</wd:Ocean_Marine_DPW>
        <wd:Inland_Marine_DPW>0</wd:Inland_Marine_DPW>
        <wd:Earthquake_DPW>0</wd:Earthquake_DPW>
        <wd:Workers_Compensation_DPW>2894</wd:Workers_Compensation_DPW>
        <wd:Other_Liability_Occurrence_DPW>0</wd:Other_Liability_Occurrence_DPW>
        <wd:Other_Liability_Claims_Made_DPW>0</wd:Other_Liability_Claims_Made_DPW>
        <wd:Excess_Workers_Compensation_DPW>0</wd:Excess_Workers_Compensation_DPW>
        <wd:Products_Liability_Occurrence_State_Page_DPW>0</wd:Products_Liability_Occurrence_State_Page_DPW>
        <wd:Products_Liability_Claims_Made_State_Page_DPW>0</wd:Products_Liability_Claims_Made_State_Page_DPW>
        <wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_No_Fault_DPW>0</wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_No_Fault_DPW>
        <wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_Liability_Other_DPW>0</wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_Liability_Other_DPW>
        <wd:Commercial_Auto_No_Fault_DPW>0</wd:Commercial_Auto_No_Fault_DPW>
        <wd:Commercial_Auto_Liability_Other_DPW>0</wd:Commercial_Auto_Liability_Other_DPW>
        <wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_Physical_Damage_DPW>0</wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_Physical_Damage_DPW>
        <wd:Commercial_Auto_Physical_Damage_DPW>0</wd:Commercial_Auto_Physical_Damage_DPW>
        <wd:Aircraft_DPW>0</wd:Aircraft_DPW>
        <wd:Fidelity_DPW>0</wd:Fidelity_DPW>
        <wd:Surety_DPW>0</wd:Surety_DPW>
        <wd:Burglary_Theft_DPW>0</wd:Burglary_Theft_DPW>
        <wd:Boiler_Machinery_DPW>0</wd:Boiler_Machinery_DPW>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

This structure is repeating multiple times with multiple regions (regions might repeat as well)
I have to achieve an output XML which will sum each element for the same regions and then after doing a sum of each element. I have to display the sum of all elements for a region.

The output should be like -

```
<Direct_Premiums_Written xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Page_14_Direct_Premiums_Written"
                         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                         xmlns:statutorytype="us-stat-2020-annual-stmt-pc"
                         xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2001/instance"
                         xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xe.com/iso4217.htm"
                         xmlns:stat="urn:www-iasa-org/tempuri">
   <stat:explAKFireDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKFireDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKAlliedLinesDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKAlliedLinesDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKPrivateFloodDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKPrivateFloodDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKFarmownersMultiplePerilDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKFarmownersMultiplePerilDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKHomeownersMultiplePerilDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKHomeownersMultiplePerilDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKCommercialMultiplePerilNonLiabilityPortionDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKCommercialMultiplePerilNonLiabilityPortionDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKCommercialMultiplePerilLiabilityPortionDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKCommercialMultiplePerilLiabilityPortionDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKOceanMarineDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKOceanMarineDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKInlandMarineDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKInlandMarineDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKEarthquakeDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKEarthquakeDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKWorkersCompensationDirectPremiumsWritten>-13203</stat:explAKWorkersCompensationDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKOtherLiabilityOccurrenceDirectPremiumsWritten>-1765</stat:explAKOtherLiabilityOccurrenceDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKOtherLiabilityClaimsMadeDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKOtherLiabilityClaimsMadeDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKExcessWorkersCompensationDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKExcessWorkersCompensationDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKProductsLiabilityDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKProductsLiabilityDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKPrivatePassengerAutoNoFaultDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKPrivatePassengerAutoNoFaultDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKOtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiabilityDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKOtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiabilityDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKCommercialAutoNoFaultDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKCommercialAutoNoFaultDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKOtherCommercialAutoLiabilityDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKOtherCommercialAutoLiabilityDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKPrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamageDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKPrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamageDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKCommercialAutoPhysicalDamageDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKCommercialAutoPhysicalDamageDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKAircraftDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKAircraftDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKFidelityDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKFidelityDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKSuretyDirectPremiumsWritten>-1575</stat:explAKSuretyDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKBurglaryAndTheftDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKBurglaryAndTheftDirectPremiumsWritten>
   <stat:explAKBoilerAndMachineryDirectPremiumsWritten>0</stat:explAKBoilerAndMachineryDirectPremiumsWritten>
<stat:explTotalsADirectPremiumsWritten>sum of all above elements for ergion AK</stat:explTotalsADirectPremiumsWritten>
continue next region....
```

Till now I have an xslt which is doing sum of individual elements but I am not sure how I can add all derived elements at the end.

The xslt is like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Page_14_Direct_Premiums_Written"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:statutorytype="us-stat-2020-annual-stmt-pc"
    xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2001/instance" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xe.com/iso4217.htm"
    xmlns:stat="urn:www-iasa-org/tempuri" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
        <Direct_Premiums_Written>

            <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry" group-by="wd:Region">
                <xsl:sort select="wd:Region" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:variable name="tag1">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'FireDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag1}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Fire_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag2">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'AlliedLinesDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag2}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Allied_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag3">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'PrivateFloodDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag3}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Private_Flood_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag4">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'FarmownersMultiplePerilDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag4}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Farmowners_Multiple_Peril_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag5">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'HomeownersMultiplePerilDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag5}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Homeowners_Multiple_Peril_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag6">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'CommercialMultiplePerilNonLiabilityPortionDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag6}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Commercial_Multiple_Peril_Non-Liability_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag7">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'CommercialMultiplePerilLiabilityPortionDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag7}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:CF_SCommercial_Multiple_Peril_Liability_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag8">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'OceanMarineDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag8}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Ocean_Marine_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag9">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'InlandMarineDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag9}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Inland_Marine_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag10">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'EarthquakeDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag10}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Earthquake_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag11">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'WorkersCompensationDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag11}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Workers_Compensation_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag12">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'OtherLiabilityOccurrenceDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag12}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Other_Liability_Occurrence_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag13">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'OtherLiabilityClaimsMadeDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag13}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Other_Liability_Claims_Made_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag14">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'ExcessWorkersCompensationDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag14}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Excess_Workers_Compensation_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag15">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'ProductsLiabilityDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag15}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Products_Liability_Occurrence_State_Page_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag16">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'PrivatePassengerAutoNoFaultDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag16}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_No_Fault_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag17">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiabilityDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag17}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_Liability_Other_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag18">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'CommercialAutoNoFaultDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag18}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Commercial_Auto_No_Fault_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag19">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'OtherCommercialAutoLiabilityDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag19}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Commercial_Auto_Liability_Other_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag20">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamageDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag20}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Private_Passenger_Auto_Physical_Damage_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag21">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'CommercialAutoPhysicalDamageDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag21}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Commercial_Auto_Physical_Damage_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag22">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'AircraftDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag22}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Aircraft_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag23">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'FidelityDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag23}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Fidelity_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag24">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'SuretyDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag24}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Surety_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag25">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'BurglaryAndTheftDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag25}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Burglary_Theft_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:variable name="tag26">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('stat:expl', current-group()[1]/wd:Region, 'BoilerAndMachineryDirectPremiumsWritten')"
                    />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$tag26}">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="sum(current-group()/wd:Boiler_Machinery_DPW)"/>
                </xsl:element>

            </xsl:for-each-group>
            
        </Direct_Premiums_Written>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an inner grouping

```
<xsl:variable name="region" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*[. castable as xs:decimal]" group-by="node-name(.)">
  <xsl:element name="stat:expl{$region}{replace(local-name(), '_', '')}">
     <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group())"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

plus

```
<stat:explTotalsADirectPremiumsWritten>
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/*[. castable as xs:decimal])"/>>
</stat:explTotalsADirectPremiumsWritten>
```

for the totals of all elements.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I used the logic for the sum and it worked but it is giving me value like this    <stat:explTotalsADirectPremiumsWritten>-2.7605954799999995E6&gt;
                </stat:explTotalsADirectPremiumsWritten>. Can we show this as a whole number without the decimal or till 2 decimal places?

Comment: Also, for the first logic, for the replace function, it is giving error coz it is taking the first parameter with the report namespace like "urn:com.workday.report/Page14_Direct_Premiums_Written",Fire_DPW. How can this be corrected?

Comment: @VJain, use e.g. `sum(current-group()/xs:decimal(.))` for better precision and of course you can then use `format-number` as needed e.g. `format-number(sum(current-group()/xs:decimal(.)), '0.00')`.

Comment: @VJain, as for the replace, sorry about that, you didn't state any rules for the names of the result elements but you are right that trying with `node-name()` is probably not what your examples suggested, test whether the edit with `local-name()` as the `replace` argument works better.